# Windows docker container cannot ping host

Tags: windows, networking, docker, containers

I am running a windows docker container on a Windows Server 2016 host, running default configuration.

When running the docker container using the command:

`docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore powershell`

When I run the command:

`ping <hostIPAddress>`

It just says that the request times out.
I have checked that I can ping 8.8.8.8 and google.com etc... and even other machines on the same subnet. The only one I cannot ping is the host.

I have added '--dns ' to the 'docker run' command but this only allows me to ping the host machine via hostname and not IP.

Has anyone else seen this problem and have a solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now, have you found a solution by any chance?

Comment: Still no solution I am afraid

Comment: Couple of month later. Does anyone have a solution for this yet. I've seen that a few folks are abandoning the whole NAT idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround (I'm not willing to call it a solution):

[Windows Container Network Drivers](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31366): create a 'transparent' network:

```
docker network create -d transparent trans
```

Attach container to this network

```
docker run --network=trans ...
```

**Important**: Please note, that with this network, your container needs to obtain an IP Adress from the Host Subnet and it is directly exposed to it.

#### maybe related (this is about access the containers from the host):

According to https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/253#issuecomment-217975932 (JMesser81):

> This is a known limitation in our Windows NAT implementation (WinNAT) that you cannot access the external port in a static port mapping directly from the container (NAT) host.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a corporate managed McAfee firewall running on my Windows host.  I could not add any additional rules on the firewall, but fortunately there was a rule that allowed access from 172.16.0.0/24.

I used "docker network create -d transparent trans" and it worked as described, but I was not happy with an IP from my host network assigned to the container.

I did the following:

- docker network create --driver=nat --subnet=172.16.0.0/24 br0
- Added --network=br0 to my docker run command

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this might help somebody.

On Windows 10 when hosting a Linux container on 0.0.0.0:5057 I was able to ping my server from my Windows host (powershell) using the IP address of the vEthernet (Default Switch) NIC found in Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Network Connections:

[image: Win10 host IP of Linux Container]

Comment: Original question was how to ping host from Docker container, not how to ping container from the host.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.

My workaround is to restart docker service, afterwards it works fine. I'm still looking for a permanent solution.

```
root@a6c40eb25cbf:/# ping xxx.xx.xx.xxx
PING xxx.xx.xx.xxx (xxx.xx.xx.xxx): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=37 time=3.541 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=2.643 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=1.857 ms
^C--- xxx.xx.xx.xxx ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I hope it works for you.

Currently, you must have **WSL** or **WSL2** installed and have **Virtualization** enabled to run **Docker on Windows**.
The installation of WSL from PowerShell is with the following [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

Obviously you need to download and install [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) on Windows. It will be necessary to enable the WSL integration from the Docker desktop settings after installing it.

[image]

After configuring WSL and Docker Desktop, you can create/use your containers. Example:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

Finally you must identify the **IP** of **WSL**, you must open the Linux distribution that you installed in the first step, in our case Ubuntu, **this will open your terminal** and here we will execute:

```
ifconfig
```

and you will identify the ip of **eth0**. Example: **172.27.123.123**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.27.123.123  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.27.127.255
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fecf:b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:5d:cf:00:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4389  bytes 299784 (299.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4343  bytes 315643 (315.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Now you can ping from CMD in Windows to this IP.

***NOTE: the connection will depend on the port of your container, example:*** **172.27.123.123:8080.**

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem while trying to use Xdebug with Docker and WSL2. I tried everything from changing VSCode/Xdebug settings, disabling firewalls, and various internet/network troubleshooting steps, but nothing seemed to fix it or suggest any reason why my Docker container couldn't access my WSL2 host IP.

Finally, in desperation I uninstalled Docker and reinstalled it and voilà---Xdebug magically works again! So if all else fails, try reinstalling Docker Desktop.