# Why can't I ping docker container on Windows?

Tags: networking, docker

Don't mark it as duplicate, because I looked at the other answers and it doesn't solve my problem.

I am using Windows 7 and docker toolbox.

I am doing this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/microservices

So after this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:5000 --name hello-docker weather-microservice
```

I am not able to reach http://localhost/

So to troubleshoot it, I decided to ping the box. But I can't.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                   COMMAND                 CREATED         STATUS      PORTS                   NAMES
78179117b516    weather-microservice    "dotnet out/Weathe..."  18 hours ago    Up 18 hours 0.0.0.0:80->5000/tcp    hello-docker
```

The following doesn't work:

```
$ docker-machine ip weather-microservice
Host does not exist: "weather-microservice"

$ docker-machine ip hello-docker
Host does not exist: "hello-docker"

$ docker-machine ip 78179117b516
Host does not exist: "78179117b516"

$ docker inspect 78179117b516
[
    {
        "Id": "78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c",
        "Created": "2017-06-27T23:37:12.147696044Z",
        "Path": "dotnet",
        "Args": [
            "out/WeatherMicroservice.dll",
            "--server.urls",
            "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 22059,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-06-27T23:37:12.339014063Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:0f6481b4a6fb864ecddb36c48a9facfbe30801d328daf59926e1c6c642f3ae24",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c/78179117b516332c61e393a36cc10f33e0f0b0d2f418d8483b79f90207e0de3c-json.log",
        "Name": "/hello-docker",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                25,
                80
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "78179117b516",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=1.0.0-rc4-004771",
                "DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/1.0.0-rc4-004771/dotnet-dev-debian-x64.1.0.0-rc4-004771.tar.gz",
                "NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "weather-microservice",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "dotnet",
                "out/WeatherMicroservice.dll",
                "--server.urls",
                "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "f1b934a02a8ac2e83bf68485d2dfb138b859d1e7b3beb4cb7ba966c9e3f4befa",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f1b934a02a8a",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "9c555071437b1919db7c539f0bd3946b7a32f92dcf49c684dbbe01e0592b9af5",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "6226280f22a5aaaa50c60d6f1a19ae8f7243bb79634c4394f62b21a10a868e48",
                    "EndpointID": "9c555071437b1919db7c539f0bd3946b7a32f92dcf49c684dbbe01e0592b9af5",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

So when I do this:

```
$ ping 172.17.0.2

Pinging 172.17.0.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

This works:

```
$ docker exec -it 78179117b516 ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.3.196): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.3.196: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=5.412 ms
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: does `-p 8080:5000` and accessing `http://localhost:8080` work?

Comment: nope @talkdirty

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I got the IP of my container from Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections. There was an adapter called vEthernet(DockerNAT) and it was the container's adapter. I could ping the IP I found for this adapter.

Comment: Why this isn't listed anywhere in any other forum or documentation I've looked through is beyond me. This was the ONLY way I found to find the correct IPV4 address to use

Comment: Yes but this is not much different from localhost. There is one, it doesn't seem like the container's own adapter, just docker's. So if I publish port 80 on one instance and 81 on another they will all have the same IP, and you still juggle with ports. What if I want to run 5 web servers, each on a different IP, all with port 80, each having a nice dev domain pointed to them from hosts file?

Answer (score 11):

It's because, the ip address you see via `docker inspect` command, is used by docker for internal networking and communication. It's not accessible from outside. Also, localhost won't work, since you are running docker toolbox, which runs inside ubuntu VM. You have to get the ip address of the VM first by,

```
docker-machine ls
```

If my memory serves right and toolbox works the same in Mac and Windows works, the ip address should be 192.168.99.100. So, you will be able to reach your app via, http://192.168.99.100. Besides all these, why are you still using docker tool box. The new way is docker for mac/ docker for windows. It's way much easier and efficient. For start, you will be able to reach your app via localhost, without needing to know the ip address.

Comment: `docker-machine ls` gives me this `tcp://192.168.99.101:2376`. when i ping `192.168.99.101`, it works, but curl it, and i get connection refused error. As for why I am not using native docker is because it is not available for Windows 7, only for Win 10. Win 7 has to use docker toolbox.

Comment: I don't think docker-machine has that rest url available. If you have completed the whole app, you could check one of those rest urls they have mentioned in their website.. http://192.168.99.101/?lat=35.5&long=40.75

Comment: `docker-machine` no longer supported on newer versions of docker. Could you update your answer please?

Comment: @Imad right, this answer is applicable only when you use docker toolbox, which was discontinues in favor of Docker Desktop. In newer Docker desktop, this question itself is invalid, since you can reach the applications via localhost.

Comment: @techtabu, any way of reaching it via the specific IP instead of localhost?

Comment: I am not understanding your question completely. The answer depends on the network settings of the computer/ VM in which docker is installed. You should be able to use the IP address of your computer/ VM. If you can ask another question explaining your situation, some one should be able to answer.

Answer (score 8):

As stated here in [Docker Known Limitations](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers):

> Docker Desktop for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers. However, you can ping the Windows containers.

So keep that in mind when trying to ping a container from Windows host to Linux container. You probably want to use the `publish` feature of `docker run` to enable **port-forwarding**.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/ => 
Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers.

Answer (score 2):

9 out of 10 times, it's windows firewall.

disable Windows Firewall entirely - turn it off - and see if you can get to your site.

Comment: I have no rights to turn off firewall on my local... I'll try to request...

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Ehsan Mirsaeedi said, but for me it was the vEthernet (Default Switch) that was the right one. Also posted an answer, with picture, on [Windows docker container cannot ping host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074576/windows-docker-container-cannot-ping-host/61272886#61272886)

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question as I was looking for a way to bind my local HTTP port 80 to the HTTP port of my container, an Apache container running on Docker Desktop for Windows, through WSL2 (this is important).

You must bind your local port (on Windows) to the port on WSL.

Here is how I did it :

```
$wsl_ip = (wsl -d "docker-desktop" -- "ifconfig" "eth0" "|" "grep" "inet addr:").trim("").split(":").split()[2]
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=443 connectaddress=$wsl_ip
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80 connectaddress=$wsl_ip
```

You can either create a Powershell Script (.ps1) and run it with Powershell, or copy/paste each command line into Windows Terminal/Powershell running with Administrator privileges.

What this does is:

1. Attach to the "docker-desktop" distribution running in WSL2 2
2. Run "ifconfig eth0 | grep inet addr:" to get the local IP address of the "virtual machine"
3. Parse the result, and use [Netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http) to create a portproxy between port 80 of your Windows machine and port 80 of your Linux machine. The same is done for port 443. You can easily
   map other ports if you understand what the command is doing.

Since Docker for Windows 10/11 uses WSL2, when you expose a port through docker-compose or with an EXPOSE command in your Dockerfile, it is exposed to a Linux distribution called "docker-desktop" that runs with WSL2. For some reason, ports 80 and 443 that are exposed from a container are NOT forwarded to the host.
The official documentation [acknowledges some issues](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/) but their solution is just to use another port, for example, 8080 mapped to 80.

The issue with this method is: Each time you reboot your system or WSL2, the Linux machine gets assigned a new IP and you have to do it again. What you could do is setup a command to run when your container starts that connects through SSH to the host and runs the script, but I'm too lazy to have done it myself.