# Jenkins dashboard does not show at localhost:8080 when launched from Windows Docker WSL2

Tags: docker, jenkins, wsl-2

Windows 10 Home, WSL2, Jenkins 2.263, Docker

I am learning Jenkins and doing the tutorial by Starmer.

In an ubuntu terminal (Windows 10 Home WSL2) I ran the provided code:

```
useradd jenkins -m
docker run \
  -u jenkins \
  --rm \
  -d \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /home/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
cat /home/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

But when I open localhost:8080 in my browser, **instead of seeing the Jenkins dashboard**, I see

[image: screenshot of localhost]

But when I stop the container from Docker and launch Jenkins from `java -jar jenkins.war` then I can see the dashboard at localhost:8080

I also tried deleting the jenkins folder, and the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image from Docker Desktop and pulled again and get

```
cat: /home/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working. I don't know what fixed it but these are what I tried:

1. In Docker Desktop, reset all data to factory defaults
2. Created ubuntu root password and did a `su -`
3. Turned off experimental Docker feature "cloud enabled".
4. I found the secret admin password in the Console in Docker desktop, **not** in the ubuntu shell.

Now I was able to go to localhost:8080 and enter the admin password.